# Why is it Object.assign() rather than this.assign() (for objects)?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm working on a JavaScript project, and was just wondering why an object instance doesn't inherit the `assign()` and other methods, rather than having to call the superclass (superobject?) `Object` method.

Why is it Object.assign() rather than this.assign() (for objects)?

Comment: Because every constructor in the millions of lines of legacy code creates objects that would have to be able to find those on the base `Object.prototype` object, and the chances of collision with common names like "assign" would be pretty great. (Even non-legacy brand-new code would have to work around those symbols.)

Comment: How do you create your object? -> Prototypal Inheritance

Comment: That's just my supposition however; you'd have to poll the language committee or look for old email threads etc.

Comment: I think that there is a "cost" for adding another method to each one of the `Object`'s instances rather than having it stored in one place, unlike `toString` or `valueOf` that are been added to each one of the instances.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way inheritance works in JavaScript. Quoting from

*[JavaScript For Beginners: the ‘new’ operator](https://codeburst.io/javascript-for-beginners-the-new-operator-cee35beb669e)*

> When you use `new`, four things happen:
>
> 1. It creates a new, empty object.
> 2. It binds `this` to our newly created
>    object.
> 3. It adds a property onto our newly created object called
>    “**proto**” which points to the constructor function’s prototype
>    object.
> 4. It adds a `return this` to the end of the function, so that the
>    object that is created is returned from the function.

So the super object method's aren't copied to the new object. They're accessible through the newly created object's prototype.